# How to "stage" file movements before performing them on Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, files, directory, mv

I have a disk with terabytes of data. I would like to reorganize the disk.

The problem on Windows is that if I move one of the directories to the new place, I have to wait hours for that relocation to finish.

Is there some way for me to "stage" all of the changes I want to make before they begin being made? I would like to spend days or weeks coming up with a new organization structure before I finally press "go" and have the files all move around.

Comment: Just write a script to perform all the moves.

Comment: Like EEAA said, just write a script or create the new folder structure on your old disk, move all the files into the new structure and then move the whole thing.

Comment: @EEAA Of course for any question you can answer "just write a program to do it." I'm asking if there's already a program - preferably one with a user interface - to do this for me so that I don't have to write my own to do it.